# How to solve "Failed to create route route1 exception" in Apache Camel?

Tags: java, apache-camel

I am new for Apache Camel concept. I have tried to write sample code using with apache camel API's 
and I am getting the following exception when try to run the code.

***Can anyone help me to solve this issue?***

Here's the sample code and an exception as well,

***Sample Code :***

```
 CamelContext context = new DefaultCamelContext();
 context.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() { 
  public void configure() {
    from("direct:start")
    .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_URI,simple("`http://sample-host:8080/demo/get`"))
    .to("http://emptyhost");
  }
 });
 context.start();
 ProducerTemplate template = context.createProducerTemplate();
 System.out.println(template.requestBodyAndHeaders("direct:start", null, null,String.class));
```

***Exception :***

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.camel.FailedToCreateRouteException: 
Failed to create route route1 at: 
    >>> To[`http://sample-host:8080/demo/get`] <<< 
in route: Route(route1)
    [[From[direct:start]] -> [`To[http://sample-host:8`…
because of 
    Failed to resolve endpoint: `http://sample-host:8080/demo/get`
due to: 
    No component found with scheme: http
```

Comment: You need to put camel-http library on your classpath

Comment: Thanks lot Konstantin V. Salikhov, Now, It's woking fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dependency libraries were missing. So i have added those libraries and solved my issue.

Comment: Hi, I have the same issue. Can you describe where, how and which dependencies you added? Thank you!

Comment: @stanly I had the same error but in this case I had forgotten to add a colon between the component and its options i.e. .to("log?level=INFO&showBody=true")

The correct configuration is:
.to("log:?level=INFO&showBody=true")

Comment: It would be useful to mention the missing dependencies, I have the same error message, but it doe not mention which dependencies exactly are missing.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error, dis is due to use of latest dependencies. so use the older dependencies and try.

Comment: This was published as an answer, but does not attempt to answer the question. Possibly it should be a comment

Comment: Hi @borchvm. It may be a little light on substance, but it does try to answer with `[...]due to use of latest dependencies. so use the older dependencies [...]`.

Answer (score 0):

After using these issue is resolved and I'm able to get the response.
I'm using below dependencies.

```
<properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <camel.version>3.11.4</camel.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.camel/camel-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-core</artifactId>
            <version>${camel.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.camel/camel-http -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-http</artifactId>
            <version>${camel.version}</version>
        </dependency>
</dependencies>
```