# Could not process Dynamic {} org.apache.camel.FailedToCreateRouteException: Failed to create route

Tags: java, apache-camel

I'm facing this issue. Anyone can help me with the resolution?

It says No bean could be found in the registry later it is throwing this error. But when I checked the bean, the bean is defined properly

Answer (score 1):

At these two links [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21802003/how-to-solve-failed-to-create-route-route1-exception-in-apache-camel) and [2](https://facingissuesonit.com/2020/04/13/org-apache-camel-failedtocreaterouteexception-failed-to-create-route-route1-routeroute1fromsendemail-tosmtps-smtp-gmail-com-because-of-no-endpoint-could-be-found-for-sen/) it's suggested to check for missing dependencies.

The BeanNotFound error is different. The bean could exist but not be visible. For example, I usually annotate my bean classes with the annotation @Component, which, if forgotten, leads to the same error.